# Prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \log(x)/x=0$ using the binomial theorem (this equation satisfies $\log(x)$ of any base)

Tags: calculus, limits

My initial idea at solving the problem was, rearranging the log(x) function into a form that will include the following property of *e,*

$e=lim_{n\to\infty} (1+1/n)^n$

From there, I wanted to expand this equation using the binomial theorem such that the *n* in the denominator would cancel out and the limit would be more easier to find.

Hence, I tried the following:

$log(x)=log(e^{log(x)})$

= $log((1+{logx}/x)^x)$

and I used binomial expansion to expand the inside of the log function, but I was stuck on how to solve the problem afterwards. Can anyone give me hints or if I am going the right direction? Thanks :)

Comment: Then put $\log_a, a\in\Bbb R^+\setminus\{1\}$.

Comment: If it works for any base, don't take $e$ take an arbitrary $a$ .